# Serenity how to keep browser only one instance through the test

Tags: serenity-bdd

I'm using Serenity jbehave to automate my webapp, and I got trouble in keeping one browser instance through the test.

My app need to login to perform any test, so I don't want to start new browser and login again and again every story.

I tried the setting below but it seem not work as expected. I am using Serenity 1.5.rc-1 with latest Firefox and Chrome, my test always open new browser every story run, if I run 5 stores, then there are 5 instance of Firefox open.

I googled for 2 weeks, but I'm still stuck.

Please help!

```
serenity.properties

serenity.use.unique.browser=true
serenity.restart.browser.for.each=NEVER
restart.browser.each.scenario=false
```

Comment: in case you want more detail, I also post a topic here in thucydides user group, but not resolve yet so far, so I hope someone here may have solution. Thanks!

link detail info about my problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thucydides-users/qLCmBf_l1ks

Answer (score 1):

JBehave doesn't support using a single browser across all stories (there is no way of knowing when the suite has finished running, so no way of knowing when to shut down the browser cleanly), so the optimal setting is 

`serenity.restart.browser.for.each = story`

This is actually a good compromise, as some WebDriver instances can become flaky when run for too long with the same browser.